# How can I prevent any program starting at boot of the system? Is the procedure different for TeamViewer?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, startup, skype, autostart

When starting Xubuntu on my laptop, a lot of applications start to run (taking a big part of my CPU and energy): TeamViewer, Skype and so on and so forth. 
I don't want to uninstall them. I just want that they run when I invoke them, nothing else and nothing more. There is something to manage this?
How to prevent the startup of any program?
I am looking for something like "System Configuration Utility" of Windows.

More then the other, what I would like to disable is **TeamViewer**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open **Settings Manager** (or `xfce4-settings-manager`) and then navigate to **Session and Startup** (or directly `xfce4-settings-manager`), then open **Application Autostart** tab and uncheck some items here:

[image: xfce4-settings-manager, session and startup]

(be careful here, some components are essential)

---

TeamViewer uses other auto-start mechanism - it starts with system by SystemD. To disable it use:

```
sudo systemctl disable teamviewerd.service
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to add that it works for most of my program. It does not with **TeamViewer**. Solution?