# Re-enable TeamViewer autostart on Xubuntu 16.10

Tags: xubuntu, startup, autostart, teamviewer

Once I disabled manually the auto-execution of TeamViewer at the boot time of my Xubuntu System (like suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093778/how-can-i-prevent-any-program-starting-at-boot-of-the-system-is-the-procedure-d)) using:

```
sudo systemctl disable teamviewerd.service
```

How I can reactivate again it? Is it enough to run the following command?

```
sudo systemctl enable teamviewerd.service
```

I am asking it because I do not want to damage my OS using `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, running `systemctl enable` will enable a service, in this case `teamviewerd.service` which will allow you to remote in using Team Viewer even when the application itself isn't running.